# Logistic Regression Optimization problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, machine-learning, logistic-regression

This is our optimization problem of Logistic Regression

$$\text{find optimal}\;(w) = argmax\;\;\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{1+e^{-(y_iw^T.x_I)}}$$

I've read that sigmoid function is a [`monotonic`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) function and it's differentiable.

Let's take log on the above optimization problem,

$$\Longrightarrow argmax\;\;\sum_{i=1}^n  log\Big(\frac{1}{1+e^{-(y_iw^T.x_I)}}\Big)$$
$$\text{we know, }\;log \Big(\frac{1}{x}\Big) = -log(x)$$
$$\Longrightarrow argmax\;\;\sum_{i=1}^n - log(1+e^{-(y_iw^T.x_I)})$$
$$\Longrightarrow argmin\;\;\sum_{i=1}^nlog(1+e^{-(y_iw^T.x_I)})$$

After taking $log$ on our above optimization problem we've got this final alternative formulation for logistic regression.

$$\Longrightarrow argmin\;\;\sum_{i=1}^nlog(1+e^{-(y_iw^T.x_I)})$$

1) Why do we need to consider taking $log$ in the first place if our sigmoid ($\sigma$) function (i.e first formulation mentioned above) was already differentiable and can be used?

Comment: kind of assume it is originally a product before taking logs. The reason we take logs is whichever w maximises $f(x)$ will also maximise $\log f(x)$. The resulting calculations are often simpler and we also get a sum rather than a product. It will be easier to differentiate

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst Can you expand it a little bit? I couldn't follow.

Comment: Are you asking why the other two formulations are equivalent to the first formulation (they are, by the monotonicity of log), or are you asking why the second or third formulation is to be preferred (the first formulation is non-concave, while the second is concave and the third convex, so convex optimization techniques can be used on the latter two formulations)?

Comment: @BrianBorchers From the wikipedia on [`sigmoid`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) function it mentions that sigmoid (first formulation) is convex on one side and concave on another side. So why can't we prefer the first formulation?

Comment: Basically the original function should be the product of these sigmoid functions. It is only when you take logs that this becomes a sum. This is the main plus for using logs.The reason it is supposed to be a product is because it is a likelihood function. $x_i$ is the $i$th data